# Problem NOT displaying – Section Headers and Footers in Ms-Access reports

Tags: ms-access

I have a Summary report which uses 5 Header Sections and 5 Footer Sections.

I have used the On Print Event to calculate Totals.

My problem is that I am left with some Sections and can not remove them.
Or the summary calculations fail.

What I have tried:

A - Setting the Footer/Header Section.Visible = False

That is fine so long as there is no data in the Section – then the data values are lost.

B – Setting the Header/Footer Height to 0

That is fine so long as there is no data in the Section – then the data values are lost.

C – Setting the height of the data items to minimal values 0.0103 cm.

That is fine but you have this patch of blue (grey lines) at the start of each section.

The height depends on the number of students in each class – not helpful.

Question – Please how can I lose this patch of blue/grey?

[A Print Preview of the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ho7w.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corin,

Option A is the option you should go with. Essentially it sounds like you want to hide a section if there is no data in it. Below is a solution with VBA code that should work. If this is similar to what you are doing, then post your code so we can take a look.

```
If Me!YourValue = '' Then
    Forms!ReportName.Section(acPageFooter).Visible = False
End If
```

**EDIT:**

My apologies for not making this solution entirely clear. Please use the below link to find a reference to the way you can reference whichever section you need to suppress/hide
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.section

```
.Section(acDetail).Visible = False
.Section(1).Visible = False
```

Comment: Chance, thank you - however.. I need the data in the Sections for calculating the Summary. I have turned off the section(acPageFooter).visible = False where there is no data. This still leaves some many sections with .visible = True - creating the grey/blue lines on the report. I suspect my best bet is to change the colour of the Sections to white; this will leave a white space - I can live with that, less than ideal but - thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @Corin I have updated my answer with a link to some documentation. Look at the link for the specifics into how to reference each one of those blank sections you want to get rid of.

Comment: thank you for the update, I am just back in the UK and have to set a slot aside to look at problems. maybe in a week or so.  Thank you again.